# ACF Image Object Sizes Issue on Multisite

Tags: multisite, images, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and have added an image with the return value being an image object. In my theme I if I dump the values of the object all the URL's for sizes are the same regardless if it is `thumbnail`, `medium`, or `large`. I am doing this on a multisite.

Here is what the image object looks like:

```
(
[id] => 123
[alt] => 
[title] => My image
[caption] => 
[description] => 
[mime_type] => image/jpeg
[url] => http://example.com/files/2013/12/my_image.jpg
[width] => 5400
[height] => 3600
[sizes] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => http://example.com/files/2013/12/my_image.jpg
        [thumbnail-width] => 150
        [thumbnail-height] => 100
        [medium] => http://example.com/files/2013/12/my_image.jpg
        [medium-width] => 300
        [medium-height] => 200
        [large] => http://example.com/files/2013/12/my_image.jpg
        [large-width] => 1024
        [large-height] => 682
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the GD was not installed.